# Android Studio how do I check email address and password before starting a new activity

Tags: java, android, email, android-activity, passwords

Making a prototype app that requires an email address & password
I am quite new to java, I have tried the following method but the new activity does not open. If anyone has any helpful hints/tips it would be appreciated :)

> ```
> public class LogonScreen extends ActionBarActivity {
> private Button SignInButton;
> private EditText Emailbox,Passwordbox;
> private CheckBox RememberMe;
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_logon_screen);
>     SignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignInButton);
>     Emailbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmailBox);
>     Passwordbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordBox);
>     RememberMe = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.RememberMeBox);
> }
> ```

```
public void SignInButtonOnClick(View View){
    if(((Emailbox.getText().toString()).equals(R.string.EmailAd))&&((Passwordbox.getText().toString()).equals(R.string.password))){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MenuPage.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set `SignInButtonOnClick()` to `onClick` attribute of `SignInButton` ?

Comment: That method should be named `signInButtonOnClick`, with the lowercase initial letter, as this is Java (not C# or wherever you're from).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this, it should work.

```
if(((Emailbox.getText().toString()).equals(getString(R.string.EmailAd)))&&((Passwordbox.getText().toString()).equals(getString(R.string.password))))
```

You're `Emailbox.getText().toString()).equals(R.string.EmailAd)` doing like this which is not correct because `R.string.EmailAd` will give you unique ID assigned to this string so this condition will never true.

To get the string which is in the resources you need to call like `getString(resource_name)` and try to follow java camel cases naming convention.

@Sajad, mentioned you need to apply click listener also on the `signInButton` button

Answer (score 0):

```
SignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //your intent
        }

    });
```